# xdebug is not showing the full stack trace

Tags: php, xdebug, callstack

If I throw an exception somewhere deep in my php code, it is printed by xdebug in front with this default orange layout, if you know what i mean. Problem is, that the call stack or stack trace there is too short. It shows only the first 5 steps.
If I catch the exception directly after throwing and print the ->xdebug_message variable out, it shows the complete call stack / stack trace, which has 14 steps.

Do anybody has an idea what could cause this problem? I'm searching already the whole day for a solution.

Versions:
PHP 5.3.6
Xdebug 2.2.3

Comment: All the stacktrace settings http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace

Comment: tried already every setting to infinity...

Comment: By any chance, are you re-throwing the Exception?

Comment: Since it's 7 years ago, it's hard to remember, but I think this was the whole problem: "Re-throwing the exception".

Answer (score 2):

**xdebug.show_exception_trace**
Type: *integer*, Default value: 0
When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will show a stack trace whenever an exception is raised - even if this exception is actually caught.

Comment: This worked in the sense that it caused the whole trace to be displayed. But I don't want to display caught exceptions!